# What is the correct thing to do about apostasy in countries where Sharia is not the official legal system?

Tags: sharia, sunnah, non-muslim-countries, apostasy

Many muslims live in secular law countries where there are other religions and sometimes members of the islamic community convert to other religion. Since Sharia could not be enforced in those countries, which will be the appropiate package of measures to address this problem?

Comment: What would you want to do anyways?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do anything but to follow the verse:

> Invite to the way of your Lord with wisdom and good instruction, and
>   argue with them in a way that is best. Indeed, your Lord is most
>   knowing of who has strayed from His way, and He is most knowing of
>   who is [rightly] guided. [16:125](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/16:125)